# understand this Regular Expression and make it case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex

here this.pattern is an '@mention' of somebody's username

```
return new RegExp(`(^|\\s|> ?)@(${ this.pattern }(@(${ this.pattern }))?)`, 'gm');
```

i need to make this mention to be case-insensitive

Comment: Sorry, but did you actually search for a solution?

Comment: Use regex101 or jex im regulex to understand and "reverse engineer" such regexes

Answer (score 0):

The case insensitive flag `i` can be set:

```
return new RegExp(`(^|\\s|> ?)@(${ this.pattern }(@(${ this.pattern }))?)`, 'gmi');
```

This allows the regex to match without modifying the actual regex.